# Hubot not responding to Ping

Tags: macos, hubot

Installed hubot but it's not responding to Pinging on OSX. Sample error:

bin/hubot
botname> [Sun May 22 2016 00:24:06 GMT-0400 (EDT)] WARNING Loading scripts from hubot-scripts.json is deprecated and will be removed in 3.0 (https://github.com/github/hubot-scripts/issues/1113) in favor of packages for each script.

Your hubot-scripts.json is empty, so you just need to remove it.
[Sun May 22 2016 00:24:06 GMT-0400 (EDT)] ERROR hubot-heroku-alive included, but missing HUBOT_HEROKU_KEEPALIVE_URL. `heroku config:set HUBOT_HEROKU_KEEPALIVE_URL=$(heroku apps:info -s  | grep web-url | cut -d= -f2)`
[Sun May 22 2016 00:24:06 GMT-0400 (EDT)] INFO hubot-redis-brain: Using default redis on localhost:6379

Comment: Hmmm. Those are standard warnings and shouldn't affect hubot. How are you pinging your hubot?

Comment: The console should start immediately after these warnings.